# If Else in Order by Clause in DB API of Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-database

I have `Drupal 7` site. I am using `dbApi` of Drupal. Now  I have a query where I need to order the records.

Table Structure:-

- AlbumId
- Album Name
- Album Created Date
- Album Release Date

Now my requirement is if `Album Release Date` is not NULL then sort by it, else use the `Album Created Date` for sorting.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->condition('n.type', 'albums', '=')
        ->condition('status', 1) //Published.
        ->fields('n', array('nid'))
        ->orderBy('field_album_release_date_value', 'DESC')
        ->execute();
$result = $query->execute();
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: it is possible only by db_query("{your query with condition}");

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You should be using addExpresion($expression).

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->condition('n.type', 'albums', '=')
    ->condition('status', 1) //Published.
    ->fields('n', array('nid'));
$query->addExpression('IF(n.field_album_release_date_value is null,'
    . 'n.field_album_release_date_value, n.field_album_create_date_value)'
    . ' as available_date');
$query->orderBy('available_date', 'DESC');
$result = $query->execute();
```

Didn't test this, so you might need to tweak it, but fact is you can use addExpression to insert sql functions like min max or in your case if.